# Call Web Component Function from Angular

Tags: angular, web-component

I want to call a function of an web component that I'm using in an Angular 10 Project.

Lets say I have an Angular Component called **Foo**:

foo.component.ts:

```js
export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   @ViewChild('bar') bar: any;
   
   constructor() {  }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    //  this.bar.hello('world')
   }
}
```

foo.component.html:

```html
<h1>FOO</h1>
<wc-bar></wc-bar>
```

The webComponent **bar**  was build with VueJS and has a function called `hello`, how can I call that function?

Comment: Is the web component included as a NPM module dependency? If so, you could try to import the element and call the function in the Angular controller.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should work this way:

foo.component.ts:

```js
export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   @ViewChild('bar') bar: ElementRef<Bar>; // if you have `Bar` typings

   ngAfterViewInit(): void { // According to https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild view queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit
      this.bar.nativeElement.hello('world')
   }
}
```

foo.component.html:

```html
<h1>FOO</h1>
<wc-bar #bar></wc-bar>
```